# Overlap when joining multiple similar subjects

Tags: conjunctions, mathematics

This question stems from a maths problem that I was checking for a tutor. The problem asked:

*"2 students are in the soccer team, 3 students are in the volleyball team, and 1 student is in both soccer and volleyball team. How many students are in only the soccer team?"*

The tutor intended for the answer to be one, but I argued that it should be two, because the part of the statement that says *"2 students are in the soccer team..."* implies that the two students being referred to does not appear anywhere else in the statement. I gave the example that if I were to visit a restaurant and order *"1 burger, 1 steak, and 1 burger and steak."*, I would almost certainly receive two burgers and two steaks in total.

In general, I suggested that when using the conjunction "and" to join multiple similar subjects, it is implied that the subjects do not overlap. However, I couldn't find anything to support or deny this. Am I wrong?

Comment: If it helps, try thinking about how you might answer if you were asked to *describe the number of meat items* in your order, rather that 'make the order'.

Comment: *And* does not imply that the subjects do not overlap. This sort of problem has its own mode of logic. The propositions only work as a set, not separately. *And* simply concatenates the propositions, it does not participate in the logic of the problem in any way. The problem may be ambiguous in some modes of reasoning, but it is unambiguous in this mode of reasoning, and that is what is being taught here. The idea is that you can get a lot across with a very few words if you stick to one set of rules.

Comment: @Phil Sweet. I would agree that the context of the question (...a maths problem) would suggest how the statement should be interpreted. But what if we were to look at the statement on its own, without considering that it is a maths problem? I would think that it is not appropriate for a question to be phrased in such a way that lends itself to multiple interpretation, depending on whether you are looking at the question on its own or as a maths question.

If the reader were to see such statements in a newspaper, novel, or magazine, how should it be interpreted?

Comment: I'd love Cort and Aparente as customers. "2 students in the soccer team..." by itself implies nothing but what it says on the page; certainly not that those two appear nowhere else…

Half the point of lessons like that is to learn to avoid such traps, whether they're taught through ordinary logic or specific set theory.

The problem and answer as stated are both perfectly clear. The only possible query linguistic, logical or arithmetic is whether to count only the students listed, or both teams in total…

The answer supports the general rule: questions contain all needed information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your question fits ELU SE, but I'll try to answer it anyway.

Yes, in my opinion you are wrong.

If two students are on the soccer team and one student is on both the soccer team and the volleyball team, then there is only one student who is only on the soccer team. It's as simple as that.

There is nothing wrong with the way the question is stated.

Comment: I tend to disagree with you. I don't think the mathematical question is sufficiently explicit and you could argue either way. Were I answering it, I would find it necessary to add a rider e.g. "1, (on the assumption that the student in both teams has already been counted in each).

Comment: @WS2 I take your point, but your rider is implicit the way people normally word mathematical problems such this. It appears to be a straightforward problem in Venn diagrams. Let S = number of students on the soccer team and V = the number of students on the volleyball team. Then we have S = 2, V = 3, and SandV = 1. Hence, SandV = 1  implies SnotV = 1 and VnotS = 2. I don't see anything wrong with the wording of the question when viewed in its obvious mathematical context (other than that the third instance of "team" should be "teams", as noted by telessent).

Comment: Except that on this site we are not discussing mathematics but English language. The former may structure it's syntax to conform to algebraic logic, but that doesn't make it correct or grammatical English.

Comment: @WS2 Which is why I said I wasn't sure this question belongs on this site. Apart from a few minor issues, there is nothing wrong with the statement of the problem from a *grammatical* standpoint. At the same time, its statement is precise from a mathematical standpoint; all the information necessary for the problem to be well-defined is there. For example, if one takes literally the statements "two students are on the S team" and "one student is on both the S and V teams", one would conclude that the one student on the  Sand V teams must be one of the two students on the S team. Let's move on.

Answer (score 1):

The question would be clearer like this:

> 2 of my friends are in the soccer team, and 3 of my friends are in the volleyball team.  1 of these friends is in both soccer and volleyball team. How many of my friends are in the soccer team but not the volleyball team?

(As the problem was originally written, these teams do not seem to be fielding enough players to compete against other schools.)  But I have to say, rewritten or not, the problem is lousy.  The tutor should just start over from scratch.

Comment: Yep, nicely done, that's definitely a clearer statement of the problem, but there is nothing wrong with the original statement. That's math (maths) for you! The answer is still one.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the question is flawed because, to get the 'correct' answer of '1', the total number of students in the population being considered has to be assumed as being five. Because the population is not stated, it could, for example, have been a class of thirty, in which case the answer would not be determinable.  The question should be prefaced with 'In a group of five students...'

Additionally, 'team' at the end of the first sentence of the question should take the plural form 'teams' because it refers to two teams.

Comment: "Because the population is not stated, it could, for example, have been a class of thirty". No, it couldn't be. That is what is being taught here. If something is not required, it is not part of the problem and you do not consider those cases. The propositions are a stand-alone set and they define the domain of the problem. You can't add things to them.